# Bash sort CSV large file and output sorted to separate files

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix, awk

I have large (4GB) semicolon-separated file (`1.txt`):

```
 - "3321";"<a href='/files/goods/edit/647/'><u>[ID 647]</u></a> Шорты";"2015-09-06 18:39:17";"1590";"1";"500";"";"Лейла";"878785";"Да";"80.140.1.38"
 - "2780";"<a href='/files/goods/edit/647/'><u>[ID 647]</u></a> Шорты";"2015-09-06 18:42:51";"1590";"1";"500";"";"Мара";"8664456";"Да";"46.00.00.2"
 - "3352";"<a href='/files/goods/edit/698/'><u>[ID 698]</u></a> Deck";"2015-09-06 19:05:42";"990";"1";"400";"";"Ed";"456452";"Нет";"80.26.00.00"
 - "3764";"<a href='/files/goods/edit/669/'><u>[ID 669]</u></a> Fish";"2015-09-06 18:36:18";"1390";"1";"530";"";"Ann";"545566";"Нет";"80.00.35.90"
 - "3323";"<a href='/files/goods/edit/669/'><u>[ID 669]</u></a> Fish";"2015-09-06 18:54:18";"1390";"1";"530";"";"юрий";"99393";"Да";"85.141.00.100"
 - "32763";"<a href='/files/goods/edit/430/'><u>[ID 430]</u></a> Radio";"2015-09-06
```

I need sort `1.txt` by second column and output all result to separate files depending on second column name.

I do this:

```
sed -r -i -e 's#"<a href=\x27\/files\/goods\/edit\/##g' 1.txt | sed -r -i -e 's#\/\x27>#;#g' 1.txt | sort --field-separator=';' --key=2 1.txt
```

But how now to split `1.txt` file and put all same ID (second column) value lines to separate file and count records in file? To have something like  `647_count.txt`, `698_count.txt`, `669_count.txt`, `430_count.txt`.

Comment: seems like file name `647_count.txt` contains the last section of the second column `"<a href='/files/goods/edit/647/'>"` but not *count records in file*

Comment: 647_count.txt contains nothing as i don know how to do that

Comment: I meant the file name, not the contents. Should the file name contain `ID` value?

Comment: should contain ID and count of records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `awk` script(let's call it `parser.awk`):

```
BEGIN { FS=";"; }   # field separator
{ 
    if (match($2, /[0-9]+/)) {           # matching `ID` value
        m=substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        a[m]++;                          # accumulating number of lines for each `ID`
        print > m"_count.txt";    # writing lines pertaining to certain `ID` into respective file
    } 
}
END {
    for(i in a) { 
        print "mv "i"_count.txt "i"_"a[i]".txt"  # renaming files with actual counts
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
awk -f parser.awk 1.csv | sh
```

For the input fragment you have posted in the question I've obtained the following list of files:

```
430_1.txt 
647_2.txt 
669_2.txt
698_1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash:

```
err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

#the line sorting
re='^[^;]*;[^;]*ID ([0-9][0-9]*)'
n=0
while read -r line
do
    let n++
    if [[ "$line" =~ $re ]]
    then
        echo "$line" >> "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_COUNT.csv"
    else
        err "$n-th line [$line] doesn't match"
    fi

done

#rename the ID_COUNT.csv to the real value of lines
shopt -s nullglob
for file in [0-9][0-9]*_COUNT.csv
do
    mv -n "$file" "${file//_COUNT/_$(grep -c '^' "$file")}"
done
```